# How to get height in percentage instead of in pixels from inline style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically, I have many elements with an inline style of `height` with percentages. Although, when I am trying to save the height as a variable to use, it is saving it as pixels.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="height:10%;">Testing 123</div>
    <div style="height:20%;">Testing 123</div>
    <div style="height:30%;">Testing 123</div>
</div>

$('.wrapper > div').each(function () {
    var height = $(this).css('height');
    console.log(height);  
});
```

The above code will print to the console `40px`, `80px` and `120px`. I need these values as percentages. Is there a way to do this, or should I save these values in a data attribute to use?

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b427X/1/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.wrapper > div').each(function () {
    var height = this.style.height;
    console.log(height); 
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b427X/3/)**

Comment: Seriously... `$(this)[0]` really? Is `this.style.height` too short or something?

Comment: var height = this.style.height;

Answer (score 1):

as said by Felix you can use `$(this)[0]` but below code also works

```
$('.wrapper > div').each(function () {
    var height = this.style.height;
    alert(height); 
});
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/b427X/1/